# Swift 3 - Returning an integer value within an If condition

Tags: swift, if-statement, return-value

just an issue I'm having with logically getting the following function to work. I feel like I'm very close; but I can't seem to figure out the logistics behind getting the else statement to not be ignored.

```
func changeEffects(_ test: Int) -> Int {
        var test = 0


        if test == 0 {

        buttonPlayer.volume = 0
        audioPlayer.volume = 0

        return test += 1
        }

        else
        {

            buttonPlayer.volume = 100
            audioPlayer.volume = 100
        return test -= 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: why is `var test = 0` here?

Comment: Since you have initialised test as 0, it will always execute if condition only.

Comment: Silly mistake var test = 0  It to make globally.
Other wise if if test == 0 condition true

Comment: In other words: remove `var test = 0`.

Comment: Yep really silly mistake here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time **changeEffects** called function first you initialise **test = 0** object
that because every return value is zero that for remove that one statement.

Below code for that:

```
func changeEffects(_ test: Int) -> Int {

    if test == 0 {

    buttonPlayer.volume = 0
    audioPlayer.volume = 0

    return test + 1
    }

    else
    {

        buttonPlayer.volume = 100
        audioPlayer.volume = 100
    return test - 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code work whenever you call the func, `test` is always be `0`.

Use code like this below to make it dynamic

```
func changeEffects(_ aTest: Int) -> Int {
    var test = aTest // do change here


    if test == 0 {

    buttonPlayer.volume = 0
    audioPlayer.volume = 0

    return test += 1
    }

    else
    {

        buttonPlayer.volume = 100
        audioPlayer.volume = 100
    return test -= 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting test as argument, you don't need to initialise it again

```
 func changeEffects(_ test: Int) -> Int {

        if test == 0 {

        buttonPlayer.volume = 0
        audioPlayer.volume = 0

        return test + 1
        }

        else
        {

            buttonPlayer.volume = 100
            audioPlayer.volume = 100
        return test - 1
        }
    }
```